# Displaying a list of items with Swing from bottom to top

Tags: java, swing

I need to display items in a list (read-only), but instead of the default top-to-bottom way of displaying a list, I need to display it bottom-to-top.

```
+-----------------+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|          value 3|
|          value 2|
|          value 1|
+-----------------+
```

If a new item is added, it should be added to the list like this  :

```
+-----------------+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|          value 4|
|          value 3|
|          value 2|
|          value 1|
+-----------------+
```

I couldn't find a Swing component allowing me to do this.
I have no experience in Swing and don't really know how I could solve this problem.

Comment: Cross posted in another forum. The OP was given a potential answer there 12 hours ago and has yet to respond to the posting, so be prepared to spoon feed the answer.

Comment: Do you require the visual representation of the list to be a constant height, e.g. 7 as you've drawn? That will call for padding the list with blank entries until you have enough "real" data.

Comment: @Carl : ideally, the height should not be constant, but if it makes it easier, I could do with it !

Comment: By the way my suggestion works but I guess you don't care since you responded to all other suggestions.

Comment: @camickr : I do care, and I'm trying all suggestions. But yours takes time, as I have no idea yet how to react to item addition and dialog resizing !

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean it "takes time"? Of course it takes time, you are attempting to custom the UI of a components. It up to you to spend the time, not us.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your code, each new item (`value4`, in your example) must be added to the list somewhere by adding it to a list model.  Let's assume that your list is called `list` and that it is backed by a `DefaultListModel` called `listModel`, like this:

```
// Create a new list of items
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(listModel);
```

Somewhere, you have code that actually adds new elements, like this:

```
public void addNewElement(Object elementToAdd)
{
    listModel.addElement(elementToAdd);
}
```

If you want to always add new elements at the beginning of the list, then you should just change the code to call `insertElementAt()` instead of `addElement()`, like this:

```
public void addNewElement(Object elementToAdd)
{
    listModel.insertElementAt(elementToAdd, 0);
}
```

Meanwhile, if your `JList` is displayed inside of a larger space, and you would like your `JList` to hug the bottom of the space, then you can put your `JList` inside of a `JPanel` and tell it to stick to the bottom of the `JPanel` using a `BorderLayout`.

So, for example, if you used to put your list into a `JScrollPane`, like this:

```
JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
```

you could instead put your list into a `JPanel` that is the same color as the background of the list, and then you could put that list inside the scroll pane instead:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.setBackground(list.getBackground());
panel.add(list, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Box containing glue and your list to the scrollpane.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your listener method that listens for a new item:

```
    String labelText = new String();
    for(int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        labelText = list.get(i) + "<br>" + labelText;
    }
    label.setText(labelText);
```